# Accessing a function inside a function from another module/file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**index.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import './index.css'
    import SquareBox from './game-buttons.js'


    const Game = () => {
      return (
        <div className="main-container">
          <i id="reset-icon" className="fas-disabled fas fa-redo-alt" onClick={() => SquareBox.resetGame}></i>
          <SquareBox />
        </div>
      )
    }


    ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById('root'));

    export default Game;
```

**game-buttons.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Game from './index.js'
import './index.css'



const SquareBox = () => {

    // reset game
    function resetGame () {
        console.log("Game reset");
    }

   return (
        <div>
            Testing
        </div >
    )
}


export default SquareBox
```

I am new to reactJS. Trying to figure out how can I access **resetGame()** function inside **game-buttons.js** by clicking **< i >** tag icon inside **index.js.**

Comment: You can't. But why don't you move this method out of the component and export it?

Comment: @YoannAugen I want to get access of some states(hooks) declared in SquareBox() through resetGame()

Comment: @YoannAugen the requirement is possible;

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what OP would like to do:
You should elevate the method resetGame to the Game component, place  inside of SquareBox and pass down the function resetGame as prop, maybe something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import SquareBox from './game-buttons.js'


class Game extends React.Component {

// reset game
function resetGame () {
        console.log("Game reset");
}

render() {
     return (
         <div className="main-container">

         <SquareBox handleClick={() => this.resetGame} />
        </div>
     )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default Game;
```

**game-buttons.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Game from './index.js'
import './index.css'



const SquareBox = ({handleClick}) => {



   return (
        <div>
            <i id="reset-icon" className="fas-disabled fas fa-redo-alt" onClick={() => handleClick}></i>
        </div >
    )
}


export default SquareBox
```

Comment: Is it an ironic comment suggesting something or simply a statement? If you could clarify what are your needs maybe we could expand the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can access inner methods of class components by passing them `ref`
in order to do that make the `squareBox` component a `class` component and then access it properties from the parents by calling it's `ref.resetGame` 
check out the 
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sunset-exg17?file=/src/App.js)

```js
class SquareBox extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.resetGame = this.resetGame.bind(this);
  }
  // reset game
  resetGame = () => {
    console.log("Game reset");
  };
  render() {
    return <div>Testing</div>;
  }
}

const Game = () => {
  let sb = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <button
        id="reset-icon"
        className="fas-disabled fas fa-redo-alt"
        onClick={() => sb.current? sb.current.resetGame() : undefined}
      >
        reset
      </button>
      <SquareBox ref={sb} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Game/>, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```